# Implicit Differentiation for calculating area of a circle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am working on a implicit differentiation equation of a circle where the radius grows by 1/per sec.

Can someone advise if I have differentiate the equation correctly?

The radius of the circle grows by 1/s given:
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = 1$$

The area of the circle given:
$$A = \pi r^2$$

Differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to the third variable: time
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 2\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}$$

The differentiation of the left hand side of the equation:
$$\frac{d}{dt}[A] = \frac{dA}{dt}$$

The differentiation of the right hand side of the equation: 
$$\frac{d}{dt} [\pi r^2] = [f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)]\frac{dr}{dt}$$

$$= [\pi\frac{d}{dr}[r^2] + r^2 \frac{d}{dr}[\pi]]\frac{dr}{dt}$$

$$= 2\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}$$

$$= 2\pi r$$ (since dr/dt = 1)

Comment: its correct. Continuing with the given values will give the answer you require

Comment: @TheIntegrator "A" should not be treated as a constant since it is dependent on $$A = \pi r^2$$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes , if you want you can write it as $A(r)$ to be more clear

Comment: What's $\frac 1 s$ ?

Comment: @BCLC OP means one per second ie $1 s^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\pi$ is a constant, all you have to do is $$ \frac {dA}{dt} =   2 \pi r\frac{dr}{dt}$$

You do not need to do the product rule in this case.

Comment: yes, the derivative of a constant is zero and anything multiply by it ends up as zero. =)